# Unable to find a region via the region provider chain error when getting AmazonS3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have below method to return AmazonS3 for upload documents. In local env, I have to connect to a s3 bucket in a different region but in other environments the s3 bucket and the application code is same aws region.

```
 public AmazonS3 getAmazonS3Client() {
        if ("local".equals(hostEnvironment)) {
            final AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest()
                    .withRoleArn("arnrole").withRoleSessionName("s3Session");
            final AssumeRoleResult assumeRoleResult = AWSSecurityTokenServiceAsyncClientBuilder.defaultClient()
                    .assumeRole(roleRequest);    
            final Credentials sessionCredentials = assumeRoleResult.getCredentials();
            final BasicSessionCredentials basicSessionCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
                    sessionCredentials.getAccessKeyId(), sessionCredentials.getSecretAccessKey(),
                    sessionCredentials.getSessionToken());
            return AmazonS3Client.builder().withRegion("us-east-2").withCredentials
            (new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicSessionCredentials)).build();
        } else {
            return AmazonS3Client.builder().withRegion("us-east-2").withCredentials
                    (new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(true)).build();
        }    
    }
```

I am getting below exception when running from local, what am I missing here?

> Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to find a region
>   via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the
>   builder or setup environment to supply a region.  at
>   com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.setRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:462)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.configureMutableProperties(AwsClientBuilder.java:424)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsAsyncClientBuilder.build(AwsAsyncClientBuilder.java:80)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceAsyncClientBuilder.defaultClient(AWSSecurityTokenServiceAsyncClientBuilder.java:45)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I set the region to AmazonS3Client,this works

AmazonS3Client amazonS3 = new AmazonS3Client(basicSessionCredentials);
amazonS3.setRegion(RegionUtils.getRegion("us-east-2"));